# Heroku, Rails 7 CI test pipeline, database errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-ci, heroku-pipelines

I'm trying to get Heroku Pipeline working with my Rails 7 application. Currently running into problems related to database connection / creation. In the pipeline test tab all tests fails and I get the following error:

```
Running 245 tests in parallel using 4 processes
We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database  configuration file located at config/database.yml.
To resolve this issue:
- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create   your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct   database name.
To create your database, run:
    bin/rails db:create
Couldn't create 'd7cd1vu5hke8mq-0' database. Please check your configuration.

[...]

DRb::DRbRemoteError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.
To resolve this issue:
- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.
To create your database, run:
    bin/rails db:create
(ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
```

I'm quite new to Heroku CI and Pipelines overall. My `config/database.yml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['WS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production
```

My production database works fine, but the errors occurs when running tests on Heroku.

I've also created a `app.json` file, but this didn't help either:

```
{
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons":[
        "heroku-postgresql:mini",
        "heroku-redis:mini"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why my database connection and test suite won't run properly?

Comment: Haver you tried running `rails db:create` or `rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: @crodev When I run `heroku rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` I get the following error:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
```

...

```
Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
```

Only `rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test` I get `Database 'db/test' already exists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `user`, `password`, and `port` settings in `database.yml` there is a solid doc explaining `why` here: [Rails Database Connection Behavior](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

And use `heroku-postgresql:in-dyno` addon for postgres tests in `app.json` as described here: [Heroku CI In-Dyno Databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases). You'll want the same for your Redis test env.

```
{
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons":[
        "heroku-postgresql:in-dyno",
        "heroku-redis:in-dyno"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```